# Using Ansible environment and assume a role with boto3

Tags: ansible, boto3

I've run into an issue assuming a role when using the environment setting to set proxies on a task.

For example, if I use a custom module with proxy_env set:

```
  - name: compare values from api
    my_custom_module:
      module_data: "{{ some_var }}"
    register: cpmared_vals
    environment: "{{ proxy_env }}"
```

I get this error:

> botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials

however if I remove 'environment: "{{ proxy_env }}"' it works.

This is what proxy_env looks like:

```
proxy_env:
  https_proxy: "http://corp-proxy.com:80"
  http_proxy: "http://corp-proxy.com:80"
  no_proxy: "internal-apps.com"
```

Thanks

Comment: As far as I'm looking at the error message, I seem that credentials need for the proxy.  
Don't you need credentials to connect to the proxy?  
Or if Ansible host has proxy configured that may be a priority.

Comment: Then I'd presume you need to teach `boto` about your custom HTTPS certificate and/or exempt the AWS endpoints from the proxy

Comment: @sky_jokerxx, the http proxy does not need credentials and I tried adding * to the no_proxy variable so everything would bypass the proxy.

Comment: @mdaniel I tried adding * to the no_proxy variable so everything would bypass the proxy. no change.